# Looking for a fantasy book with a red haired girl heroine

Tags: story-identification

I read it about ten years ago. It was about a girl whose mother (advanced species, white skin, red hair) crashed on some backwards planet, was raped by the the chief of some patriarchal clan with strict religious rules. The spacer gave birth to a daughter then skipped the planet leaving her behind. When the girl grows up she is almost killed by her clan, because of some foggy prophecy that her offspring will destroy the planet. She escapes with the help of her lover (a bard who is caught by the clan and as punishment, is blinded.) The book is about the adventures of how the girl finds a way to leave the planet. If I remember correctly, she in the end leaves with some smuggler guy on his ship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the book you are looking for is Diadem from the stars by Jo Clayton. This is the first book in the Diadem series - 
Diadem from the Stars (1977)
Irsud (1978)
Lamarchos (1978)
Maeve (1979)
Star Hunters (1980)
The Nowhere Hunt (1981)

The girls mother was Shareem - a member of an advanced race called the Vyrhh. The girl was called Aleytys. The boyfriend who was blinded is Vajd.

Description of the first book (pinched from goodreads) ALEYTYS THE FUGITIVE
Far out among the stars the masterminds of the spider people had placed their mightiest mysteries in the scientific device called the diadem. And when that coronet was stolen, they were prepared to pursue it throughout eternity.

The thief crashed among the nomads of Jaydugar, a semi-barbarian world... and the diadem found its way into the hands - and onto the skull - of the girl Aleytys.

She was herself a strange one - daughter of a sky wanderer, outcast among the people who had raised her out of fear and awe. And the diadem was to prove both her bane and her treasure. For she could not remove it once it had sunk its electronic web into her brain and her nervous system - and she did not know how to control the powers that were contained within it.

Yet every moment she wore it, she would be a target for the vengeance of the spider race and the avarice of a thousand worlds.